# What value does the following series converge to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

How would I find the value that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(kn)!}$ converges to? The motivation behind this question is that I am trying to find out how to show what value that series of the sum of reciprocal of factorials converge to and I am stumped for the case where k=3 and k=5

Comment: I would just ask Alpha.  I would expect a numeric answer rather than a symbolic one.  You could even make a spreadsheet as it will converge rapidly.  Three terms give twelve places, five terms give 25.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @AnotherUser thank you very much for the advice :)

Comment: @RossMillikan Contrary to your expectations, if you asked [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%281%2F%285*n%29%21%2C+n%3D0..infinity%29) you would get a closed form (see the section ""Alternate form")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask a more general question: Find a closed form expression for $$f_k(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{kn}}{(kn)!}$$

To get your answer, you can just plug in $x=1$. My solution below uses Laplace transform, I think I can add another one that doesn't use it (at least for $k=3,5$).

---

**The idea:** Apply Laplace transform to both sides and use $\mathcal{L}\{x^j\}=\frac{j!}{s^{j+1}}$, then the Laplace transform of $f_k$ (denoted $F_k$) is
$$F_k(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(kn)!}{(kn)!s^{kn+1} } = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{s^{kn+1} }=\frac{s^{k-1}}{s^k-1}$$

---

The case $k=3$: We have $F_3(s)=\frac{s^2}{s^3-1}$. Apply a partial fraction decomposition to get
$$F_3(s)=\frac{2 s+1}{3 \left(s^2+s+1\right)}+\frac{1}{3 (s-1)}$$
Then you can apply the inverse transform to get

$$\boxed{f_3(x)=\frac{e^x}{3}+\frac{2}{3} e^{-\frac{x}{2}} \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right)}$$

To find the sum that you are looking for, just plug in $1$  $$f_3(1)=\frac{e}{3}+\frac{2 \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}{3 \sqrt{e}}.$$

---

The case $k=5$ can be done similarly but the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{s^4}{s^5-1}$ is nasty, I used Mathematica:

$$F_5(x)=\frac{s^4}{s^5-1},\qquad f_5(x)=\frac{1}{5} \left(e^x+2 e^{-\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right) x} \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)} x\right)+2 e^{\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right) x} \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}+5\right)} x\right)\right)$$

When you plug in $1$, you get

$$\frac{1}{5} \left(e+2 e^{\frac{1}{4} \left(-\sqrt{5}-1\right)} \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)}\right)+2 e^{\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)} \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}+5\right)}\right)\right)$$

---

**Conjecture:** For any $k\ge 0$, we have

$$\boxed{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(kn)!} =\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\exp\left(\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i j}{k}\right)\right)}$$

I believe this conjecture to be true because the partial fraction decomp. of $\frac{s^{k-1}}{s^k-1}$ should be expressed in terms of $\frac{1}{s-e_k^j}$ where $e_k$ is the k-th root of unity.

Comment: Wow! Absolutely amazing. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

We know that $$\sum\frac{z^n}{n!}=e^z.$$One can use a trick with roots of unity to add several instances of this identity and magically come up with the sum you want.

Let $\alpha=e^{2\pi i/3}$ and $\beta=\alpha^2$. Verify that for $n\in\Bbb N$ we have $$1^n+\alpha^n+\beta^n=\begin{cases} 0,&(3\not|n),
\\3,&(3|n).\end{cases}$$So with the power series above this shows that $$e+e^\alpha+e^\beta=3\sum\frac1{(3n)!}.$$

A precisely similar trick gives your sum.

Cool. What actually happened here was this: We want to find $$\sum\frac{c_n}{n!}.$$
Turns out if $(c_n)$ is a periodic sequence with period $k$ we can do this using a Fourier expansion of $c_n$ in terms of $k$th roots of unity...